# How to change globals() from inside a function?

Tags: python, spyder

While running this code inside a function, Globals() are not updated.

```
fpath= dir1+'/data1_.spydata'
globals().update(load_dictionary(fpath)[0])
```

When running outside, as a script, globals() is updated.
How to make it run from a function ?

Thanks

Comment: Simple answer : don't. globals are evil.

Comment: You definitely can update `globals()` from a function, though I would refrain from it by all means.

Comment: It should work from a function. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You should probably declare the variable as a global in the [beginning of the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them). But if you can [avoid globals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: This is to load variables into globals()..... Not about Global variables, it seems there is a lot of confusion in the answers.